# Connect Rally Web Services API authentication with 401

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, rally

I am try to access Rally api by using .ajax. So far I did try basic auth. I keep got error 401. my code as below:

```
adminUn = rallyuser;
adminPw = rallyuserpassword;
var tok = adminUn + ':' + adminPw;
var hash = Base64.encode(tok);
var authCredentials = "Basic " + hash;
url = https://rally1.rallydev.com

function jQueryGetMethod (url, data) {
 $.ajax({
   url: url,
   type: 'GET', // The HTTP Method
   mimeType: 'application/javascript',
   datatype: 'json',
   error: function(err) { alert(err); },
   complete: function(xhr) {
     if (xhr.status === 200) {
       repositories = xhr.responseJSON;
       outputPageContent();
 }
 else {
     alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
 }
   },
   error: function( req, status, err ) { console.log( 'something went wrong', status, err );
 },
   beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) { xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization',authCredentials);
       xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');}
 });
```

}

I also wondering how to get a know user's profile? such as projects this user currently under?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an app I came up with that has a user picker at the top and it will load a grid of the selected user's project permissions:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>UserPermissionsExplorer</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.1/sdk.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Rally.onReady(function () {
            Ext.define('CustomApp', {
                extend: 'Rally.app.App',
                componentCls: 'app',

                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align: 'stretch'
                },

                padding: '10px',

                launch: function() {
                    this.add({
                        xtype: 'rallyusersearchcombobox',
                        project: this.getContext().getProjectRef(),
                        fieldLabel: 'Select a user:', 
                        width: 300,
                        listeners: {
                            select: this._onUserSelected,
                            scope: this
                        } 
                    });
                },

                _onUserSelected: function(userCombo) {
                    var store = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
                        model: 'ProjectPermission',
                        filters: [{
                            property: 'User',
                            operator: '=',
                            value: userCombo.getValue()
                        }],
                        pageSize: 25,
                        context: this.getContext().getDataContext(),
                        autoLoad: true
                    });

                    var grid = this.down('rallygrid');
                    if (grid) {
                        grid.reconfigure(store);
                    } else {
                        this.add({
                            xtype: 'rallygrid',
                            flex: 1,
                            columnCfgs: [
                                'Project',
                                'Role'
                            ],
                            context: this.getContext(),
                            enableEditing: false,
                            showRowActionsColumn: false,
                            store: store
                        });
                    }
                }
            });


            Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
                name:"UserPermissionsExplorer",
                parentRepos:""
            });

        });
    </script>



    <style type="text/css">
        .app {
            /* Add app styles here */
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle, I will go through that. I have one more question. If I got username ABCD, is there any way I can list which projects ABCD currently been added to?

Comment: Once you have a user you can load that user's userpermissions collection (/user/<objectid>/userpermissions) and that will give you a list of all the permissions and role for each project.

Comment: Hi Kyle, Could you please give me a full sample on how to do it? I think I got some hard time on how to use the SDK.